# Is wordpress supposed to automatically load images over https?

Tags: image, wordpress, ssl, https

When I try to access my website over https, I get a mixed content error. Looking at the console, The offending resources are all images that are uploaded using the wordpress media uploader. 
But isn't wordpress smart enough to know that it should serve those images over ssl if the https version of the website is requested? If not, is there an easy solution to resolve this issue (besides from editing every post to replace say http://example.com/image.jpg with //example.com/image.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Wordpress has a plugin that does this trick. [Wordpress HTTPS(SSL)](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/screenshots/)

It replaced all images loaded through "HTTP" with "HTTPS".